# Splice on collections

Tags: c#, collections

In perl, the splice function returns a new array of items from an existing array and at the same time removes these items from the existing array.

```
my @newarry = splice @oldarray, 0, 250;
```

`@newarray` will now contain 250 records from `@oldarray` and `@oldarray` is 250 records less.

Is there an equivalent for the C# collection classes ie Array, List, Queue, Stack with a similar function? So far I have only seen solutions where two steps are required (return + remove).

Update - no functionality exists so I have implemented an extensio method to support the Splice function:

```
public static List<T>Splice<T>(this List<T> Source, int Start, int Size) 
{
  List<T> retVal = Source.Skip(Start).Take(Size).ToList<T>();
  Source.RemoveRange(Start, Size);
  return retVal;
}
```

With the following Unit test - which succeeds:

```
[TestClass]
public class ListTest
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void ListsSplice()
  {
    var lst = new List<string>() {
      "one",
      "two",
      "three",
      "four",
      "five"
    };

    var newList = lst.Splice(0, 2);

    Assert.AreEqual(newList.Count, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(lst.Count, 3);

    Assert.AreEqual(newList[0], "one");
    Assert.AreEqual(newList[1], "two");

    Assert.AreEqual(lst[0], "three");
    Assert.AreEqual(lst[1], "four");
    Assert.AreEqual(lst[2], "five");

  }
}
```

Comment: There's no direct equivalent in the .NET collection classes. You could, of course, write your own helper method that does return+remove. How do you intend to use the method? Perhaps there is a more C#ish way of doing it instead of trying to carry a pattern over from Perl.

Comment: Thank you - I have created an extension method to add the splice function to lists - this could possibly also be further generalized to support IEnumerables.

Comment: You could replace `Source.Skip(Start).Take(Size).ToList<T>()` by `Source.GetRange(Start,Size)`.

Comment: post your update as an answer and accept it, will be easier for future generations to find your solution, also check collection sizes to avoid unnecessary exceptions

Comment: @SADeveloper: Reminder: Answer your question instead of having the answer as a part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a Splice method with an extension. This method simply get a range (which is a copy of the referenced object in the list), then it removes the objects from the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpliceExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

            List<int> subset = numbers.Splice(3, 3);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbers)); // Prints 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", subset));  // Prints 4, 5, 6

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

  static class MyExtensions
  {
      public static List<T> Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int index, int count)
      {
          List<T> range = list.GetRange(index, count);
          list.RemoveRange(index, count);
          return range;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only [`Stack.Pop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.pop.aspx) and [`Queue.Dequeue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97.aspx) which will return and remove one item but not multiple.

If you need this behavior you have to write it on your one, but maybe you can simply wrap one of the above. But you should define what happens if the user defines a greater number than elements available or a number of zero or less.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of spliced elements is bigger then the number of elements in a list then GetRange() and RemoveRange() methods throw an exception. The better solution is to use Skip() and Take() and check for List size:

```
    public static class ListExtension
    {
      public static List<T> Splice<T>(this List<T> source, int start, int size)
      {
          var items = source.Skip(start).Take(size).ToList<T>(); 
          if (source.Count >= size)
              source.RemoveRange(start, size);
          else 
              source.Clear();
          return items;
      }
    }
```